# How to apply an effect on sound from mic realtime during the call?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, callkit, avaudioengine

My app makes calls via Twilio Voice SDK using `CallKIt`. I want to apply some effect (e.g. increase voice speed) on sound from my mic so that the other person can hear the sound after applying the effect.

I found the solution here:
https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios/blob/master/AudioDeviceExample/AudioDevices/ExampleAVAudioEngineDevice.m

I modified this example for my task and Twilio voice SDK. I was able to apply some effect to the sound from the mic but only on the Twilio side. The caller will hear the unchanged sound, and the modified sound will only be recorded if you save the conversation using Twilio SDK. It also reduces sound quality in both directions.

Can I change the sound from mic locally in the same way so that the other person can here already changed the sound? How can I do this if it's possible?

This is a part of the code, when I'm applying pitch effect to mic sound:

```c
[engine attachNode:pitch];

AVAudioFormat *format = [[AVAudioFormat alloc] initWithCommonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatFloat32 sampleRate:44100 channels:2 interleaved:false];

[engine connect:pitch to:engine.mainMixerNode format:[engine.inputNode inputFormatForBus:0]];
[engine connect:engine.mainMixerNode to:engine.outputNode format:format];
```